# How to properly define a model/layer which includes shape operation in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I encounter few different layout failed issues when my layers require shape operation like reshape, get input's shape. I carefully wrapped those ops with tensorflow ops like `tf.shape(x)` and get nhwc with `tf.gather_nd()`. But still somehow get some errors like this:

```
layout failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::SortTopologically error: detected edge(s) creating cycle(s)...
```

and normally with a lot of i don't know what layer info:

```
...
dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/
while/dormand_prince/while/body/_140529/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/advance_to_solution_time/while/exit/_254210' -> 'dorman
d_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/body/_140529/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_pr
ince/while/advance_to_solution_time/while/LoopExecuted/_254425', 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dorma
nd_prince/while/next_iteration/_141777-0-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer' -> 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradie
nts_13/while/dormand_prince/while/merge/_140901', 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while
/exit/_141485' -> 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/IdentityN', 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_
39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/exit/_141485' -> 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13
/while/dormand_prince/while/LoopExecuted/_141734', 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/whil
e/body/_140529/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/advance_to_solution_time/while/exit/_254227' -> 'dormand_princeGradients_13/whil
e/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/body/_140529/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/advance_to_sol
ution_time/while/LoopExecuted/_254425', 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/next_iter
ation/_141794-0-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer' -> 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prin
ce/while/merge/_140918', 'dormand_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/dormand_prince/while/exit/_141502' -> 'dorman
d_princeGradients_13/while/body/_39932/dormand_princeGradients_13/while/IdentityN',
...
```

It seems like it had some trouble when converting NHWC to NCHW. It can be solved by setting
`tf.config.optimizer.set_experimental_options({'layout_optimizer': False})` but is there something else solution for `layout failed` or is there some rules to follow when layer requires modifying shape of tensor?